# Call a function passing a file name from dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a file name from dynamically created table and getting some Uncaught ReferenceError: Q1_58_English_Resume is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (AddRequirement:1)

Here the file name is "Q1_58_English_Resume"

The script for dynamic table is below

if (filesData.length > 0) {

```
    var table = '';
    table += '<table class="radar-grid-table" id="TableAttach">';
    table += '<thead>';
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<th>Files</th>'
    //table += '<th>Select</th>';
    table += '<th>Actions</th>';

    table += '</tr>';
    table += '</thead>';
    table += '<tbody>';
    $.each(filesData, function (i, item) {
        table += '<tr>';
        table += '<td>' + item + '</td>';
        //table += '<td title="' + item.AttachmentId + '">' + item.AttachmentId + '</td>';
        //<input value="' + full.QuestionId + '
        table += '<td> <a href="#" id="mylink" onclick="DownloadAttachment('+item+')">Download</a> </td>';

        table += '</tr>';
    });
    table += '</tbody>';
    table += '</table>';

    return table;

}
```

And the Function is below:

```
function DownloadAttachment(fileName) {
    debugger;
    var url = "/RequirementManagement/OpenFile?ids=" + fileName;
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: You need quotes around `item` in `"DownloadAttachment('+item+')"` i.e. `"DownloadAttachment(\''+item+'\')"`

Comment: Any idea if I want to pass 2 parameters. How to do it.

Comment: If a string you would use `"DownloadAttachment(\''+item+'\', \''+param + '\')"`, otherwise `"DownloadAttachment(\''+item+'\','+param + ')"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this , should work

```
var table = '';
    table += '<table class="radar-grid-table" id="TableAttach">';
    table += '<thead>';
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<th>Files</th>'
    //table += '<th>Select</th>';
    table += '<th>Actions</th>';

    table += '</tr>';
    table += '</thead>';
    table += '<tbody>';
    $.each(filesData, function (i, item) {
        table += '<tr>';
        table += '<td>' + item + '</td>';
        //table += '<td title="' + item.AttachmentId + '">' + item.AttachmentId + '</td>';
        //<input value="' + full.QuestionId + '
        table += '<td> <a href="#" id="mylink" onclick="DownloadAttachment('${item}')">Download</a> </td>';

        table += '</tr>';
    });
    table += '</tbody>';
    table += '</table>';

    return table;

}
```